# Gitlab CI - not supported: outside build directory

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, cicd

I have a problem with saving the artifact. The project is divided into 3 modules, one of them is saved and the other two are not.

Clonning project:
Cloning into '/home/gitlab-runner/builds/Gso-uWvA/0/www/project-infoserwis/../project-root
Cloning into '/home/gitlab-runner/builds/Gso-uWvA/0/www/project-infoserwis/../project-core

```
artifacts:
paths:
  - /home/gitlab-runner/builds/Gso-uWvA/0/www/project-infoserwis
  - /home/gitlab-runner/builds/Gso-uWvA/0/www/project-root
expire_in: 10 min
```

LOGS pipeline:

```
  Uploading artifacts...
  Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=24943 
  revision=54944146 version=13.10.0
  /home/gitlab-runner/builds/Gso-uWvA/0/www/project-infoserwis: found 2240 
  matching files and directories 
  
  WARNING: /home/gitlab-runner/builds/Gso-uWvA/0/www/project-root: not 
  supported: outside build directory 
  WARNING: /home/gitlab-runner/builds/Gso-uWvA/0/www/project-root/pom.xml: 
  not supported: outside build directory 
  WARNING: /home/gitlab-runner/builds/Gso-uWvA/0/www/project-root/src: not 
  supported: outside build directory 
  WARNING: /home/gitlab-runner/builds/Gso-uWvA/0/www/project-root/src/main: 
  not supported: outside build directory 
  WARNING: /home/gitlab-runner/builds/Gso-uWvA/0/www/project- 
  root/src/main/resources: not supported: outside build directory 
   WARNING: /home/gitlab-runner/builds/Gso-uWvA/0/www/project- 
   root/src/main/resources/application.properties: not supported: outside build 
   directory
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Can you please share more code of your `.gitlab-ci.yaml`?

Answer (score 9):

GitLab is only able to package [artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html) found in the `$CI_PROJECT_DIR` directory (`/home/gitlab-runner/builds/Gso-uWvA/0/www/project-infoserwis` in your example).

You should always clone git repositories and build software in folders with `./` as root directory and not use absolute paths:

```
job:
  # do git clones and builds in . ($CI_PROJECT_DIR)
  # ...
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - project-root
    expire_in: 10 min
```