# How I can turn off warnings in Gitlab-ci?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

How can I skip these warnings in Gitlab-CI?
It spams all logs in pipeline.

```
WARNING: /opt/react/b57e2b5b781b5438a08ac93a288c49a0c6113e8c/node_modules/@mui/icons-material/esm/CenterFocusWeakOutlined.js: not supported: outside build directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should fix the warning and not sweep under the carpet.

I refer to this answer: [Gitlab CI - not supported: outside build directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69582679/gitlab-ci-not-supported-outside-build-directory)

**Summary:**
GitLab only can package artifacts found in the `$CI_PROJECT_DIR` directory (/home/gitlab-runner/builds/Gso-uWvA/0/www/your_project).

Therefore, make sure your project and it's dependencies can be found in this path. Don't use absolute paths.

Gitlab-Documentary: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html

Gitlab-Forum: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/warning-not-supported-outside-build-directory/3680/5

Comment: It isn't mistake or failure and your answer doesn't resolve it

Comment: May you can add parts of your gitlab-ci.yml to your question? Do you use artifacts?